# Mapping between JSON formats in Java

Tags: java, json

I'm coming to Java from JavaScript/Ruby. Let's say I've got the following JSON object for an animal:

```
{
  name: {
    common: "Tiger",
    latin: "Panthera tigris"
  }
  legs: 4
}
```

I'm dealing with lots of animal APIs, and I want to normalize them all into my own common format, like:

```
{
  common_name: "Tiger",
  latin_name: "Panthera tigris",
  limbs: {
    legs: 4,
    arms: 0
  }
}
```

In, say, JavaScript, this would be straightforward:

```
normalizeAnimal = function(original){
  return {
    common_name: original.name.common,
    latin_name: original.name.latin,
    limbs: {
      legs: original.legs || 0,
      arms: original.arms || 0
    }
  }
}
```

But what about in Java? Using the JSONObject class from org.json, I could go down the road of doing something like this:

```
public JSONObject normalizeAnimal(JSONObject original) throws JSONException{
  JSONObject name = original.getJSONObject("name");
  JSONObject limbs = new JSONObject();
  JSONObject normalized = new JSONObject();
  normalized.put("name_name", name.get("common"));
  normalized.put("latin_name", name.get("latin"));
  try{
    limbs.put("legs", original.get("legs");
  }catch(e){
    limbs.put("legs", 0);
  };
  try{
    limbs.put("arms", original.get("arms");
  }catch(e){
    limbs.put("arms", 0);
  };
  normalized.put("limbs", limbs);
  return normalized;
}
```

This gets worse as the JSON objects I'm dealing with get longer and deeper. In addition to all of this, I'm dealing with many providers for animal objects and I'll eventually be looking to have some succinct configuration format for describing the transformations (like, maybe, `"common_name": "name.common", "limbs.legs": "legs"`).

How would I go about making this suck less in Java?

Comment: (It *is* possible to run JavaScript in Java .. not that I particularly advise it for this task, but it is one [clever] approach ;-)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this? As in, what actual problem that you have is solved by sending data in the same format? Because the JavaScript interpreter doesn't care.

Comment: @parsifal, I'm allowing a another developer to plug normalized animals into their UI without having to do the parsing in their UI code. (Also they're not really animals. It's a contrived example.)

Comment: you could improve the JSONObject-using code a lot by using `if has(key)` instead of catching exceptions.

Answer (score 7):

Use a library like Gson or Jackson and map the JSON to a Java Object.

So you're going to have a bean like

```
public class JsonAnima {
    private JsonName name;
    private int legs; 
}
public class JsonName {
    private String commonName;
    private String latinName;
}
```

which can be easily converted with any library with something like (with Jackson)

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonAnimal animal = mapper.readValue(jsonString, JsonAnimal.class);
```

then you can create a "converter" to map the JsonAnimal to you Animal class.

This can be a way of doing it. : )

---

Some links:

Gson: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Jackson: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome

Comment: I don't really recommend this... not only is it unnecessary automatic serialization/deserialization but it will probably end up being more lines of code.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Anyway you can use annotations to map the right properties with your fields. : )

Comment: +1 The OP wants to make his normalizeAnimal(JSONObject) code "suck less." Json is a data interchange format, and a typical Java programmer would use Json and JSONObject only in that capacity. Thus, you convert from Json to normal Java objects on input, perform whatever processing you need on those objecs, and convert back to Json if that's also your output format. The OP also wants a succinct configuration-based transformation facility, and for that you might try Dozer (which also operates on plain Java objects.)

Comment: Gson/Jackson with Dozer is exactly what I was going to suggest. Write a Java object for each of the formats then use Dozer to map the fields of one to the fields of the other (and visa versa if necessary).

Comment: In my experience Object Mapping doesn't work when the JSON has "variable schema" or not all inbound JSON objects have the exact same structure.  You end up having to parse the JSON by hand somehow or let some framework turn it into a map of maps, of maps.  I've had success with the JacksonTreeModel to this end:  http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonTreeModel , but this is still a lot of code for little function.  I recommend doing this in Groovy or some other more dynamic language.

Answer (score 2):

The pure Java solutions all are challenged to deal with unreliable structure of your source data.  If you're running in a JVM, I recommend that you consider using Groovy to do the Parse and the Build of your source JSON.  The result ends up looking a lot like the Javascript solution you outlined above:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def originals = [
  '{ "name": { "common": "Tiger", "latin": "Panthera tigris" }, "legs": 4 }',
  '{ "name": { "common": "Gecko", "latin": "Gek-onero" }, "legs": 4, "arms": 0 }',
  '{ "name": { "common": "Liger" }, "legs": 4, "wings": 2 }',
  '{ "name": { "common": "Human", "latin": "Homo Sapien" }, "legs": 2, "arms": 2 }'
]

originals.each { orig ->

  def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
  def parsed = slurper.parseText( orig )

  def builder = new JsonBuilder()
  // This builder looks a lot like the Javascript solution, no?
  builder { 
      common_name parsed.name.common
      latin_name parsed.name.latin
      limbs {
          legs parsed.legs ?: 0
          arms parsed.arms ?: 0
      }
  }

  def normalized = builder.toString()
  println "$normalized"
}
```

Running the script above deals with "jagged" JSON (not all elements have the same attributes) and outputs like...

```
{"common_name":"Tiger","latin_name":"Panthera tigris","limbs":{"legs":4,"arms":0}}
{"common_name":"Gecko","latin_name":"Gek-onero","limbs":{"legs":4,"arms":0}}
{"common_name":"Liger","latin_name":null,"limbs":{"legs":4,"arms":0}}
{"common_name":"Human","latin_name":"Homo Sapien","limbs":{"legs":2,"arms":2}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'll be using this for many different types of objects, I would suggest to use reflection instead of serializing each object manually. By using reflection you will not need to create methods like normalizeAnimal, you just create one method or one class to do the serialization to json format.

If you search for "mapping json java" you'll find some useful references. Like gson. Here is an example that is on their website:

```
    class BagOfPrimitives {
      private int value1 = 1;
      private String value2 = "abc";
      private transient int value3 = 3;
      BagOfPrimitives() {
        // no-args constructor
      }
    }

    //(Serialization)
    BagOfPrimitives obj = new BagOfPrimitives();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(obj);  
    ///==> json is {"value1":1,"value2":"abc"}

    ///Note that you can not serialize objects with circular references since that will result in infinite recursion. 

    //(Deserialization)
    BagOfPrimitives obj2 = gson.fromJson(json, BagOfPrimitives.class);   
    //==> obj2 is just like obj
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try little [jmom](https://github.com/antonsjava/jmom) java library

```
JsonValue json = JsonParser.parse(stringvariablewithjsoninside);
Jmom mom = Jmom.instance()
    .copy("/name/common", "/common_name", true)
    .copy("/name/latin", "/latin_name", true)
    .copy("/arms", "/limbs/arms", true)
    .copy("/legs", "/limbs/legs", true)
    .remove("/name")
    ;
mom.apply(json);
String str = json.toPrettyString("  ");
```